# Where does ubuntu store information on all installed programs

Tags: package-management, software-center

I have created a custom software, packaged it as a .deb file and tried to installed the same through software-center. Everything was successful. However, when I go back to "Installed" software, I do not find the software listed there. I have tried changing the categories from the drop down in software center but still no luck.

dpkg shows me that the software is installed. apt-get also lists the software. But it is not visible in Software Center.

I have tried this in various ubuntu versions on 32 bit as well as 64 bit. The problem seems to be intermittent. Any pointers/help to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no software called 'debian package format' in Ubuntu Software Center? What is the exact name of the software? How did you test using dpkg and apt-get? Kindly edit your question and include this info.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the screen of software-center there is a link "Show NNNN technical items". Click that link.

At the top right there is a search box. Type the name of your package there.

And to answer your actual question: the information about installed packages is stored in `/var/lib/dpkg` and can be queried with `dpkg-query -l` (or various other frontends). There is no separate backend for each frontend. That is also why you get errors about a locked database when you try to run two dpkg frontends at the same time, like synaptic and software-center.