# Ubuntu Software (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) does not display installed apps

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. Unfortunately, Ubuntu Software application does not display installed apps. The screen (Installed tab) is just empty.

I have tried to follow different recommendations but nothing worked.
The last attempt was:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-software
sudo apt-get purge gnome-software
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The Ubuntu Software app has many problems; fortunately it's not necessary to use it at all.  A good GUI app to show installed software is Synaptic Package Manager - just click "Installed" in the left column.

Comment: Understood. I can handle everything via apt CLI. The only purpose of Ubuntu Software is convenient way to track updates and remove installed apps. The most strange thing is that I used to have Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 in the past and it worked! Is it better in 18.04? :)  Synaptic does not seem to locate/search packages installed via dpkg directly (e.g. Google Chrome). So the only reliable for me to check is to do something like:  apt list --installed | grep <package>

Comment: The above did not work on Ubuntu 20.04 for the issue "No installed software list on Ubuntu Software (center) nor on gnome-software manager". Neither did 'Remove/purge' and install --reinstall from console and from Synaptic. When first installed, on the first instance of Gnome Software, it did show the installed software list. Ubuntu Software has never shown the list from the first installation. This answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/752145/where-does-ubuntu-store-information-on-all-installed-programs